# lerna bootstrap info undefined@undefined~postinstall: undefined@undefined

Tags: npm-install, lerna, post-install

I have 3 repositry, react components, ts utils and react app, when I use lerna to manage them, it happens. I'm not very familiar with lerna, I want to know why it hapeened and how can I solve it.
[image]

learn repo issue has no problem like this

Answer (score 0):

Add "name" property to `package.json`.

Same Issue is here.
["npm ci" throws exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777226/npm-ci-throws-exception-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)